# Converting lump sums to transactions

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view

I have a database that tracks the size of claims.

Each claim has fixed information that is stored in `claim` (such as `claim_id` and `date_reported_to_insurer`).

Each month, I get a report which is added to the table `claim_month`. This includes fields such as `claim_id`, `month_id` [101 is 31/01/2018, 102 is 28/02/2018, etc]  and `paid_to_date`.

Since most claims don't change from month to month, I only add a record for claim_month when the figure has changed since last month. As such, a claim may have a June report and an August report, but not a July report. This would be because the amount paid to date increased in June and August, but not July.

The problem that I have now is that I want to be able to check the amount paid each month.

Consider the following example data:

```
+----------------+----------+----------------+--------------+
| claim_month_id | claim_id | month_id       | paid_to_date |
+----------------+----------+----------------+--------------+
| 1              | 1        | 6              | 1000         |
+----------------+----------+----------------+--------------+
| 5              | 1        | 7              | 1200         |
+----------------+----------+----------------+--------------+
| 7              | 2        | 6              | 500          |
+----------------+----------+----------------+--------------+
| 12             | 1        | 9              | 1400         |
+----------------+----------+----------------+--------------+
| 18             | 2        | 8              | 600          |
+----------------+----------+----------------+--------------+
```

If we assume that this is all of the information regarding claim 1 and 2, then that would suggest that they are both claims that occurred during June 2018. Their transactions should look like the following:

```
+----------------+----------+----------------+------------+
| claim_month_id | claim_id | month_id       | paid_month |
+----------------+----------+----------------+------------+
| 1              | 1        | 6              | 1000       |
+----------------+----------+----------------+------------+
| 5              | 1        | 7              | 200        |
+----------------+----------+----------------+------------+
| 7              | 2        | 6              | 500        |
+----------------+----------+----------------+------------+
| 12             | 1        | 9              | 200        |
+----------------+----------+----------------+------------+
| 18             | 2        | 8              | 100        |
+----------------+----------+----------------+------------+
```

The algorithm I'm using for this is

```
SELECT claim_month_id, 
       month_id, 
       claim_id, 
       new.paid_to_date - old.paid_to_date AS paid_to_date_change, 
FROM   claim_month AS new 
       LEFT JOIN claim_month AS old 
              ON new.claim_id = old.claim_id 
                 AND ( new.month_id > old.month_id 
                        OR old.month_id IS NULL ) 
GROUP  BY new.claim_month_id 
HAVING old.month_id = Max(old.month_id)
```

However this has two issues:

1. It seems really inefficient at dealing with claims with multiple
   records. I haven't run any benchmarking, but it's pretty obvious.
2. It doesn't show new claims. In the above example, it would only show lines 2, 3 and 5.

Where am I going wrong with my algorithm, and is there a better logic to use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LAG function to get the next `paid_to_date` of each `claim_id`, and use the current `paid_to_date` minus the next `paid_to_date`.

```
SELECT 
claim_month_id, 
claim_id, 
month_id,
paid_to_date - LAG(paid_to_date, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY claim_id ORDER BY month_id) AS paid_month
FROM claim
```

The output table is:

```
+----------------+----------+----------+------------+
| claim_month_id | claim_id | month_id | paid_month |
+----------------+----------+----------+------------+
|              1 |        1 |        6 |       1000 |
|              5 |        1 |        7 |        200 |
|             12 |        1 |        9 |        200 |
|              7 |        2 |        6 |        500 |
|             18 |        2 |        8 |        100 |
+----------------+----------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: Fantsatic, thank you for your example. I was unaware of partitioning, which looks like it will be very useful.

Comment: Yes, partitioning can be very useful when you do aggregation (i.e. sum, avg, etc.) or analytics (row_number/rank, lag/lead, first_value/last_value) **within groups**. In this case, the `claim_id` is the group.

Comment: Another comment though, the syntax LAG (a, b, c) is not part of MYSQL. MYSQL does not have the default value option so that has to be added manually.